# using a variable from a class in python

Tags: python, pygame

I think this question has been asked before but I have not found an answer suited to my problem. I basically have a class for different characters, which each have a cost. When creating a character, I want to take their cost away from the players score.

Here is an example of a class:

```
class Assassin(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, row, column):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("assassin.png")
        self.x = x
        self.type = "assassin"
        self.y = y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(self.x, self.y))
        self.damage = 60
        self.health = 40
        self.speed = 2
        self.move = False
        self.cost = 4
        self.row = row
        self.column = column
```

And here is the code where I would want to use the variable:

```
 if assassin.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and mouseDown[0]:
            for block in blockGroup:
                if block.team1Taken == False and block.column ==1:
                    team1.add(Assassin(block.team1[0], block.team1[1], block.row, block.column))
                    block.team1Taken = True
                    score -= Assassin.__init__.cost #Example of what I think you would do
                    break
```

I hope I have explained this well enough to understand what I want.

Comment: Which `Assassin`'s `cost` attribute would you like to access? The Newly created one or the one you use for the `if` condition? If the new one then follow my answer. If the one from the `if` condition, simply use `assassin.cost`

Comment: you will be a happier Python user if you always indent 4 spaces, and not vary the indentation depending on the wording of the line that starts the block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `score -= Assassin.__init__.cost` in python.
The **init** method is the constructor of the Class and should be used to do so.

The value that you want is inside the object that you created, so you could call `assassin.cost` directly, assuming that assassin is the object.

So, you just need to change to:

```
if assassin.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and mouseDown[0]:
            for block in blockGroup:
                if block.team1Taken == False and block.column ==1:
                    current_assassin = Assassin(block.team1[0], block.team1[1], block.row, block.column)
                    team1.add(current_assassin)
                    block.team1Taken = True
                    score -= current_assassin.cost
                    break
```

Comment: You should make `Assassin(block.team1[0], block.team1[1], block.row, block.column)` an object and then use it to get the cost and add it to the team1.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to keep a reference to the `Assassin` instance you create and then access its `cost` attribute:

```
if assassin.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) and mouseDown[0]:
    for block in blockGroup:
        if block.team1Taken == False and block.column == 1:
                new_assassin = Assassin(block.team1[0], block.team1[1],
                                        block.row, block.column)
                team1.add(new_assassin)
                block.team1Taken = True
                score -= new_assassin.cost
                break
```